# How do I pass data to a rootViewController of a UINavigationController in an instantiated Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here is my code. The problem is that title isn't getting passed to PinTableViewController.

From my original view:

```
NSString *title = @"testing123";

UIStoryboard *tableViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [tableViewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pinStoryboard"];

PinTableViewController *pinController = (PinTableViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
pinController.pinTitleID = title;

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

PinTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"test";
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I pass data to PinTableViewController?

Comment: Are you sure pinController isn't nil?

Answer (score 4):

You instantiate your nav controller correctly but then you try to access its root view controller by referencing self.navigationController, but those are different view controllers.  You need to access the root view of the new navigation controller.  Here is the updated line

```
PinTableViewController *pinController = (PinTableViewController *)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be complex but you can fire a notification to assign the value.

In your PinTableViewController. Put this line of code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(assignTitle:) name:@"AssignTitle" object:nil];
```

still in your PinTableViewController write this function

```
-(void)assignTitle:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSDictionary *getTitle=[notification userInfo];

   self.title (or whatever you want to assign the title to) = [getTitle objectForKey:@"Title"];
}
```

Now from your Original view

```
NSString *title = @"testing123";

UIStoryboard *tableViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [tableViewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pinStoryboard"];

NSMutableDictionary *titleToSend=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[titleToSend setObject:title forKey:@"Title"];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AssignTitle" object:self userInfo:titleToSend]; }];
```